# Llenar datos a un ListView personalizado desde servidor (Web Service)

Tags: php, android, mysqli, webservice

Buenas tardes.

Estoy realizando un servicio web en Android, en este caso estoy jalando datos de una tabla en MySql que tengo en un servidor para poblar un ListView personalizado.

**La consulta que tengo es que los datos que intento obtener no se están poblando en el ListView. Estoy usando PHP, MySQL.**

Siendo más especifico, estoy jalando los datos de una tabla en mysql, lo guardo en una clase get set, y luego creo un arreglo de esa clase para luego poblarlo en el listview personalizado, dejaré abajo el código de todo esto.

Este es mi resultado Json que obtengo del php.

```
[{"idproducto":"1","idtipo":"1","descproducto":"Loza de tama\u00f1o 7x9","imagen":"http:\/\/appfotoceramica.pe.hu\/01.jpg"},{"idproducto":"2","idtipo":"2","descproducto":"L\u00e1pida cl\u00e1sica","imagen":"http:\/\/appfotoceramica.pe.hu\/hola.jpg"}]
```

Ahora este es el codigo en Android.

```
 public class Productos extends Activity {

  Spinner spTipoProducto;
  ListView listaProducto;
  ProgressDialog pd;

  String resultadoTotal;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 0);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_productos);

    spTipoProducto = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spSeleccionar);
    listaProducto = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaProductos);


   EjecutarTodo();

}

private String Conectar(){

    int respuesta = 0;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = null;
    String linea = "";
    URL url = null;

    try{
        url = new URL("http://appfotoceramica.pe.hu/cargarimagen.php");

        HttpURLConnection conexion = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        respuesta = conexion.getResponseCode();

        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        if(respuesta == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){

            InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(conexion.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            while((linea = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                   stringBuilder.append(linea + "\n");
            }
        }

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return resultadoTotal = stringBuilder.toString();
}

public void ObtenerJson(String result){
    try{

        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
        ProductoBean pb;

        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
        pb = new ProductoBean();

            pb.setCodigoproducto(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("idproducto"));
            pb.setIdtipo(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("idtipo"));
            pb.setDescproducto(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("descproducto"));
            pb.setImagen(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("imagen"));


        }

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

protected class HiloCargarImagen extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Object>{

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(String... strings) {
        Conectar();
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Object result){
        pd.dismiss();
        ObtenerJson(resultadoTotal);
        ArrayList<ProductoBean> productoBean = new ArrayList<ProductoBean>();
        Adaptador adaptador = new Adaptador(Productos.this, productoBean);
        listaProducto.setAdapter(adaptador);

    }
}

private void EjecutarTodo(){
    pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Cargando productos", "Espere por favor...", true, false);
    new HiloCargarImagen().execute();
  }
}
```

Este es el **adaptador para crear la personalización del ListView.**

```
    public class Adaptador extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
ArrayList<ProductoBean> pb;


public Adaptador(Context ctx, ArrayList<ProductoBean> productos){
    context = ctx;
    pb = productos;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return pb.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return pb.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    if(view == null){

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.customlistview,viewGroup,false);

        TextView tipoProducto, descProducto;
        SmartImageView imagen;

        tipoProducto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textoTipoProducto);
        descProducto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textoDescripcionProducto);
        imagen = (SmartImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagenProducto);

        int id;

        id = pb.get(i).getIdtipo();

        if(id == 1){
            tipoProducto.setText("Lozas");
        }else if(id == 2){
            tipoProducto.setText("Lápidas");
        }else if(id == 3){
            tipoProducto.setText("Tarjeteros");
        }else{
            tipoProducto.setText("Fotos 20x30");
        }

        descProducto.setText(pb.get(i).getDescproducto());
        imagen.setImageUrl(pb.get(i).getImagen());

     }

    return view;
   }
}
```

Subo de todas maneras la parte del php.

```
 <?php

$conexion =   mysqli_connect("mysql.hostinger.es","u534134956_jorge","jorgejorge","u534134956_appfo");

$query = mysqli_query($conexion, "select * from producto");

while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC){

$idproducto = $fila["idproducto"];
$idtipo = $fila["idtipo"];
$descproducto = $fila["descproducto"];
$imagen = $fila["imagen"];

  $productos[] = array("idproducto" => $idproducto, "idtipo" => $idtipo, "descproducto" => $descproducto, "imagen" => $imagen);

  }

 $json = json_encode($productos);
 echo $json;


?>
```

Comment: Lo que yo  siempre hago es descargo la informacion en la base de datos sqlite y luego de alli los jalo a Listview

Comment: Lo de la imagen tienes que usar base64 :s

Comment: @x4mp73r estoy guardándolo como url, y con una librería que tiene algo llamado SmartImageView, es parecido al ImageView, solo que te permite mostrar imágenes dándole una url.

Te dejo el link de la librería:

http://loopj.com/android-smart-image-view/

Comment: le falta el codigo los layuot
para compatibilizar todo mejor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que el problema es que estas creando instancias de ProductoBean y no estas haciendo nada con ellas, y a tu adapter le estas pasando un listado vacío, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
public ArrayList<ProductoBean> ObtenerJson(String result){
try{
    ArrayList<ProductoBean> productoBean = new ArrayList<ProductoBean>();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
    ProductoBean pb;

    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
        pb = new ProductoBean();

        pb.setCodigoproducto(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("idproducto"));
        pb.setIdtipo(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("idtipo"));
        pb.setDescproducto(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("descproducto"));
        pb.setImagen(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("imagen"));

        //Agregas a tu lista el nuevo objeto
        productoBean.add(pb);

    }
    //Devuelves el listado
    return productoBean;

  }catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

   return null;

}
```

En tu onPostExecute, obtienes el listado

```
  protected void onPostExecute(Object result){
    pd.dismiss();

    ArrayList<ProductoBean> productoBean = ObtenerJson(resultadoTotal);
    if (productoBean != null){
       Adaptador adaptador = new Adaptador(Productos.this, productoBean);
       listaProducto.setAdapter(adaptador);
    }

}
```

**Sugerencia**: Debes usar al patrón ViewHolder en tu Adapter